# How to open a Taproot channel on c-lightning node?

Tags: core-lightning, taproot

Will new channels automatically use Taproot now, or is there something to activate in c-lightning to make it use Taproot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are major protocol updates necessary before we can use taproot in lightning and decide how exactly to make use of it in lightning and how to integrate it. Thus I don't think any implementation (that includes c-lightning) as of now or even in this year will add support for it

Comment: Thanks! As I understood the messages in Muun, they already added Taproot support last year, after it activated.
We had to take some action in the wallet to enable it, if I remember right.
Did i misunderstand that?

Comment: "Taproot support" could be split into multiple different things. When Muun say they "added Taproot support" they mean they added the ability to send and receive to a Taproot address. But all the possible upgrades (gossip, MuSig2, PTLCs etc) to the Lightning Network protocol that Taproot offers haven't been implemented yet (as Antoine, Rene say)

Answer (score 4):

Channel opening is about communication between two nodes. Therefore it's not a feature C-lightning can unilaterally support. The protocol needs to be specified in the [BOLTs](https://github.com/lightning/bolts).

As of February the 21st, specifications are still being discussed on the mailing list. A concrete protocol for Taproot channel openings has not been publicly proposed yet.